# DELETE all using Left join of 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, sql-delete

```
SELECT * FROM property
LEFT JOIN installmentagreement
ON property.PId=installmentagreement.PId
LEFT JOIN installments
ON installmentagreement.Id=installments.Id
LEFT JOIN rentagreement
ON property.PId=rentagreement.PId
WHERE property.PId=39
```

This is the SELECT query that works as expected. I want to DELETE the result of this SELECT query. I used this query.

```
DELETE FROM property( SELECT * FROM property
LEFT JOIN installmentagreement
ON property.PId=installmentagreement.PId
LEFT JOIN installments
ON installmentagreement.Id=installments.Id
LEFT JOIN rentagreement
ON property.PId=rentagreement.PId
WHERE property.PId=39)
```

And this also.

```
DELETE FROM property
LEFT JOIN installmentagreement
ON property.PId=installmentagreement.PId
LEFT JOIN installments
ON installmentagreement.Id=installments.Id
LEFT JOIN rentagreement
ON property.PId=rentagreement.PId
WHERE property.PId=39
```

But it returns with Syntax Error. I want to covert the SELECT query into DELETE query. The DB I am using is MySQL.If there is any other better solution please suggest. Please help!

Comment: ehrm...it's a `LEFT JOIN`, so shouldn't this just be `DELETE FROM property WHERE PId = 39`?

Comment: use a cte, perhaps... assuming you are trying to delete from all the tables in your join.

Comment: No, Actually the table "InstallmentAgreement" and "RentAgreement" contains the foreign Key of table "Property". While the table "Installments" contain the foreign key of table "InstallmentAgreement"

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using aliases for clarity and more:

```
SELECT *
FROM property as p
LEFT JOIN installmentagreement as ia
ON p.PId=ia.PId
LEFT JOIN installments as i
ON ia.Id=i.Id
LEFT JOIN rentagreement as ra
ON p.PId=ra.PId
WHERE p.PId=39
```

Then you can convert easily to delete statement as follows:

```
delete p
FROM property as p
LEFT JOIN installmentagreement as ia
ON p.PId=ia.PId
LEFT JOIN installments as i
ON ia.Id=i.Id
LEFT JOIN rentagreement as ra
ON p.PId=ra.PId
WHERE p.PId=39
```

And if you wanted to delete records from some of the left-joined tables before you delete the `property` records, you can just as easily change the alias in the delete statement:

```
delete ra
FROM property as p
LEFT JOIN installmentagreement as ia
ON p.PId=ia.PId
LEFT JOIN installments as i
ON ia.Id=i.Id
LEFT JOIN rentagreement as ra
ON p.PId=ra.PId
WHERE p.PId=39
```

Comment: My friend this query is fine but on records it is giving me Foreign KEY constraint error. Actually the table "InstallmentAgreement" and "RentAgreement" contains the foreign Key of table "Property". While the table "Installments" contain the foreign key of table "InstallmentAgreement". Can you fix this query to solve this constraint please. According to the error, what I understood is that first I have to DELETE the rows from the tables which contain foreign keys, i.e. "RentAgreement" , "Installments", "InstallmentAgreement" and then from the table property.

Comment: Delete in this order - ra, ia, i and p.

Comment: Tried that. Still no luck. ERROR " Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pak`.`installmentagreement`, CONSTRAINT `installmentagreement_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PId`) REFERENCES `property` (`PId`))"

Comment: If you are deleting ia before p, this error will not show up.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports deleting from multiple tables in one statement, but you need to specify the tables you want to delete from:

```
DELETE p, ima, i, ra
    FROM property p LEFT JOIN
         installmentagreement ima
         ON p.PId = ima.PId LEFT JOIN
         installments i
         ON ima.Id = i.Id LEFT JOIN
         rentagreement ra
         ON p.PId = ra.PId
WHERE p.PId = 39;
```

Of course, you don't have to include all four tables after the `DELETE`, just the ones you want to delete from.

Comment: My friend this query is fine but on records it is giving me Foreign KEY constraint error. Actually the table "InstallmentAgreement" and "RentAgreement" contains the foreign Key of table "Property". While the table "Installments" contain the foreign key of table "InstallmentAgreement". Can you fix this query to solve this constraint please. According to the error, what I understood is that first I have to DELETE the rows from the tables which contain foreign keys, i.e. "RentAgreement" , "Installments", "InstallmentAgreement" and then from the table property.

Comment: @HaseebAhmed . . . I don't know if it would make a difference, but you could try `delete ra, i, ima, p`.  You may have other records that are generating the foreign key problems.

Comment: Tried that. Still no luck. ERROR " Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pak`.`installmentagreement`, CONSTRAINT `installmentagreement_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PId`) REFERENCES `property` (`PId`))"